# How to remove rows leading up to a particular value?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

In the following data, for each `id`, I would like to remove rows after the first `1` is reached. My data is as follows:

```
 id x
  a 0
  a 0
  a 1
  a 0
  a 1
  b 0
  b 1
  b 1
  b 0
```

The desired output:

```
 id x
  a 0
  a 0
  a 1
  b 0
  b 1
```

Code to reproduce data:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"b"), x = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

This is not a duplicate question, although similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72732054/remove-rows-of-a-certain-value-before-values-change-in-r). I used `cumall()` to remove all rows after the first `1`:

```
df <- df%>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(cumall(!(x == 1))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

But the caveat here is that I want to include the row with the first `1` as well.
Any help is appreciated, preferably using `dplyr`!

Comment: `df %>% filter(cumsum(x) == x, .by = id)` should work.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento that's really smart! You should post it as an answer!

Comment: A brief elaboration would help, as I am unable to debug the errors I get using this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(y = cumall(lag(!x))) %>%
    filter(is.na(y)) %>%
    select(-y)

  id        x
  <chr> <int>
1 a         0
2 a         0
3 a         1
4 b         0
5 b         1
```

Comment: Using this code unfortunately gives me the same output that I got in my attempt i.e., I get a dataframe where all rows after and including the first `1` are removed.

Comment: did you run `df <- structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"b"), x = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))`?

Comment: Understood, your code works!

Answer (score 2):

a data.table approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[seq(1, min(which(x == 1)))], .(id)]$V1,]
```

of

```
setDT(df)[df[, .I[seq.int(min(which(x == 1)))], .(id)]$V1,]
#    id x
# 1:  a 0
# 2:  a 0
# 3:  a 1
# 4:  b 0
# 5:  b 1
```